# Improper results using Ball pivoting from VCG

Tags: geometry, mesh, meshlab, vcg

While using meshlab application, I'm able to create a mesh using the ball pivoting algorithm giving radius as 3.1952 and clustering 0.2. Results are good.

But when I call the same method using [VCG](http://vcg.isti.cnr.it/vcglib/) library giving same values of radius and clustering the output mesh is incomplete.

Here is have just filled the mesh data structure with vertices and called the api. Please suggest any modifications.

My PFA images:
[image]
[image]